# unexpected behavior of 'rpm --setperms sudo'

Tags: permissions, sudo, package-management, rpm

`rpm --setperms sudo` on a fedora 29 fresh installation sets `/usr/bin/sudo`'s permissions to 0777; i confirmed it by reinstalling sudo using dnf, which will correctly set the permissions to 4111 and then rerunning `rpm --setperms sudo` will change it back to 0777.

on fedora 28 `rpm --setperms sudo` behaves normally and correctly and sets the permissions of sudo binary to 4111.

was there a change in fedora 29 in this regard? is this to be expected? or it's a bug with sudo package or something else?

Comment: Lack of setuid could be due to using capabilities instead (haven't checked, `suexec` fooled me that way), but yeah, it pretty certainly shouldn't be `a+w`.